# Can't create JS object with array indices as key & value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, indexing

Task: convert an array into an object with one key-value pair, where the first array item is the key, and the last array item is the value.

E.g., [1,2,3] should convert to {1: 3}

I can't get it to work as:

```js
function transformFirstAndLast(array) {
  var firstLast = {
    array[0]: array[-1]
  };
  return firstLast
}
```

But only as:

```js
function transformFirstAndLast(array) {
  var firstLast = {};
  firstLast[array[0]] = array[array.length - 1];
  return firstLast
}
```

...why doesn't the first work? Why can't you index the array for the key & value?

Comment: JavaScript simply does not work that way.

Comment: array[0]: array.pop()

Comment: Because there is no array element at position -1, that’s why. The first element in an array is index 0.

Comment: @ScottMarcus so you can't do negative indexing in JS?

Comment: That’s correct.

Comment: To elaborate. An "index" must be a non-negative integer that is not higher than the highest integer JavaScript supports. Any other value passed in square brackets is treated as a "property" assignment and that property name becomes a string. So, `array[-1]` does not modify the `length` of the array, it just gives it a new property called "-1".

Answer (score 3):

You could pop the last element and take a computed property for the object. (For the first element, you could take [`Array#shift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift), if you like to do it in the same manner.)

```js
function transformFirstAndLast(array) {
    return { [array[0]]: array.pop() };
}

console.log(transformFirstAndLast([1, 2, 3]));
```

ES5 with a temporary variable.

```js
function transformFirstAndLast(array) {
    var temp = {};
    temp[array[0]] = array.pop();
    return temp;
}

console.log(transformFirstAndLast([1, 2, 3]));
```

Comment: Follow-up question: why, with the temp variable example, is it "=" instead of ":"?

Comment: because it is an assignment, not an object literal with [name/value pairs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) (which are separated by colon).

Answer (score 0):

Take the first is easy, take the last is the size minus one like this:

```js
function firstAndLast(array) {
    var ary = {};
    ary[array[0]] = array[array.length - 1];
    return ary;
}

console.log(firstAndLast([1,2,3]))
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you must remember than an array is a type of JavaScript object and, in JavaScript, an object property (a.k.a. "key") can be accessed or assigned in two ways:

**via "dot notation"**

```
object.property = value;
```

**via array syntax**

```
object["property"] = value;
```

Next, remember that, in JavaScript, if you assign a value to a property that doesn't exist (using either syntax from above), the property will be created, like in the following:

```js
console.log(window.someNewProperty);         // undefined
window.someNewProperty = 17;                 // This causes the property to be created
window["someOtherNewProperty"] = "Voilla!";  // So does this, just with array syntax
console.log(window.someNewProperty);         // 17
console.log(window["someOtherNewProperty"]); // "Voilla!"
```

Now, moving on to the specifics of an array, it's critical to understand the difference between an object property/key name (which is always represented as a string) and an array index (which is always a non-negative integer up to the max integer in JavaScript).  So, if you have an array and seemingly assign a value to a negative index, you are actually creating a property that is named the negative index and not actually adding to the length of the array or making a new indexed position in the array. We can see that here:

```js
var myArray = ["a", "b", "c"];
myArray[-1] = 15;

console.log(myArray.length);  // 3 not 4
console.log(myArray[-1]);     // 15

// Now to prove that -1 is a string name for a new property and not an index:
console.log(myArray);  // Notice no 15 in the indexed values?

// And, if we enumerate the object (not just the indexes), we'll see that we actually created 
// a property with [-1], not a new index.
for(var prop in myArray){
  // Note that prop is not the value of the property, it's the property name itself
  console.log(typeof prop, prop, myArray[prop]);
}
```

So, to sum up, Arrays have non-negative integer indexes to store the items that make up the `length` of the array, but Arrays are also objects and have properties, like all other objects do. Any bracket assignments that use anything other than non-negative integers as the key name will become new properties, not array indices.